# Assessing a property from a widget in a slide_up_panel Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen that contains a Slider_up_widget

On the main body I can pass a variable using widget.type.varaible and returns a string

```
_pageDetails.detailsMainImage(widget.barPage.barBusinessNameMainImage),
```

On my slide_up_panel I'm trying to do the same but I'm getting an error

```
  _pageDetails.businessOperating(widget.barPage.barBusinessAddr),
```

**"The getter 'barPage' isn't defined for the type 'PanelWidgetBusiness'."**

This is my panel class

```
class PanelWidgetBusiness extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController controller;
  final PanelController panelController;

  const PanelWidgetBusiness({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.panelController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PanelWidgetBusiness> createState() => _PanelWidgetBusinessState();
}

class _PanelWidgetBusinessState extends State<PanelWidgetBusiness> {
  final _pageDetails = const BarRestPageWidgets();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        controller: widget.controller,
        children: [
          // _pageDetails.businessOperating(),
          _pageDetails.businessOperating(widget.barPage.barBusinessAddr),
        ],
      );


}
```

I have tried using

```
final BarDetails barPage;
```

which removes the error but then my panelBuilder requires

**The named parameter 'barPage' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.**

What have I got to put in there to satisfy it.

```
 panelBuilder: (controller) => PanelWidgetBusiness(
          controller: controller,
          panelController: panelController, 
          barPage: null, // ←← What should I put here 
        ),
```

Is it possible to make the barpage not required in the Panel Controller.

I've tried

```
final BarDetails? barPage;
```

But then I get the error
**The property 'barBusinessAddr' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.**

And adding a ! null type can be added.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to access `widget.barPage.barBusinessAddr` in your Stateful Widget because you are not parsing any barPage in the constructor.

If you add `final BarDetails barPage;` to your `PanelWidgetBusiness` class then you are not setting the value, you are just defining variable. Because it is non-null type it **must** be a required argument in your constructor or get a different fixed value during initialization. Setting nothing is not an option in this case.

If BarPage is optional, then you can make it nullable by adding an `?`, but you need to be careful. Depending on the logic, your code could look something like this, provided your `barPage` can be null.

```
if (widget.barPage != null){
    _pageDetails.businessOperating(widget.barPage!.barBusinessAddr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the advice, I'll try to find another way to get the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as the answer as I will surely come back to it again.

On the panelcontroller you are passing parameters to the PanelWidgetBusiness() class.

```
 panelBuilder: (controller) => PanelWidgetBusiness(
          controller: controller,
          panelController: panelController, 
          barPage: null, // ←← What should I put here 
        ),
```

for the barPage you pass the widget.barPage

```
 panelBuilder: (controller) => PanelWidgetBusiness(
          controller: controller,
          panelController: panelController,
          barPage: widget.barPage // Answer
        ),
```

Now you can access all of the elements in the barpage model.

Ans can be assessed using

```
_pageDetails.businessOperating(**widget.barPage.barBusinessAddr**)
```

widget.barPage.barBusinessAddr is the main part, the rest is a Widget wrapped around it.